# search and replace values for multiple keys in a json string using pcre regex for a list of keys

Tags: regex

i am battling with a search and replace regex to replace all values for a given list of keys in a json string (1 dimensional). Here's a sample string:

```
PRE1 | PRE2 | PRE3 | some data {"key1":"foo","key2":"bar","key3":"public","key4":"alsosecret"} and then there is some more log
```

The PCRE regex needs to match the whole string, specifically based on PRE2 and rebuild it (i.e. including all the "PRE" and trailing stuff. Got to something like this:

```
/(.*\| PRE2 \|.*{)(("key1|key2|key4)":")[^"](,)?)+(}.*)$/\1\2_x_\5/g
```

I can't get it to match multiple. This is the desired replacement string:

```
PRE1 | PRE2 | PRE3 | some data {"key1":"_x_","key2":"_x_","key3":"public","key4":"_x_"} and then there is some more log
```

More context: it is for use in a Splunk transforms `Regex`, which is PCRE-compliant. It needs to match the whole event, here's an example - the match is defined in Regex and the event is indexed as per FORMAT. https://answers.splunk.com/answers/519820/masking-data-using-regex-during-indexing.html

Comment: Which language/tool are you using your regex with? Also, would it be possible to use two regexs to solve your problem or do you need to do it in one shot?

Comment: @Aaron i have updated - PCRE, and some more context on where I am using it.

Comment: i am trying to optimize many search and replace transforms into a single 1, it affects the performance of splunk and the management of config.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/AsRrk9/1) what you want?

Comment: @Toto - it's close - i want to supply a field list, e.g. the value  for `key3` should be maintained. i should be able to update your base to get it working.... will let you know.

Comment: `\G|\K` makes it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- Find: `(?:^.*?\| PRE2 \|.*?{\K|\G)(.*?"(?:key1|key2|key4)":")\w+("[,}])`
- Replace: `$1_x_$2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/AsRrk9/2)

Comment: That is great - i just got it working by replacing the first `\w+` with `(key1|key2|key4)` and then swapping the order from `\K|\G` to `\G|K` and then updating the replace to $1_x_$3 - this works wonderfully. regexfoo is strong with you.

Comment: @Brett: It seemed to that it worked fine in regex101, but if your modifications works better, it's fine. Glad it helps.

Comment: 1 other thing - the values in the JSON in the real data were a bit more complex than single strings, so instead of `)\w+(` near the end, i switched that out to `)[^"]+(` to match everything until the next closing quote (there's never an escaped closing quote in the value).